# Удалить из предложения третье слово

Tags: c

С клавиатуры ввести предложение. Удалить из этого предложения третье слово (если слов
только два – предложение не менять). Напечатать сокращенное предложение.

Comment: Вводите. Печатайте. В чем проблема?

Comment: Учебные задания допустимы в качестве вопросов только при условии, что вы пытались решить их самостоятельно перед тем, как задать вопрос. Пожалуйста, отредактируйте вопрос и укажите, что именно вызвало у вас трудности при решении задачи. Например, приведите код, который вы написали, пытаясь решить задачу

Comment: Что мешает считать слова по мере ввода, и отправить третье в NULL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://ideone.com/6ZANe9

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
  char str[256];
  
  for (unsigned q=0; ; ++q)
  {
    if (scanf("%s", str) <= 0) break;
    if (q != 2) printf("%s", str);
    if (scanf("%[\x01-\x09\x11\x12\x14-\x20\x8F]", str) <= 0) break;
    printf("%s", str);
    if (scanf("%1[\n]", str) == 1) break;
  }
  
  return 0;
}
```

```
С клавиатуры ввести предложение.
Удалить из этого предложения
```

```
С клавиатуры  предложение.
```